# wp_get_post_terms - Do Not list Duplicates

Tags: terms

I am trying to get a list of terms used by a certain post type, have been using "wp_get_post_terms" however I only want to list one instance of each term instead of listing them all.

**For Example I am currently outputting**

Term 1, Term 1, Term 1, Term 2, Term 2, Term 2

**I am trying for the following**

Term 1, Term 2

**Current Code:**

```
global $post;
$loop = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'cpt_desk_operator',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    )
);

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
    $loop->the_post();
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'operator_offers' );
    foreach ( $terms as $term_single ) {
        echo $term_single->name;
    }
endwhile;
```

Comment: `$terms = array_unique( $terms );`. [array_unique()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php).

Comment: Why are you doing a `WP_Query` to loop through all posts? When you're only interested in the unique list of terms used by that post type, you can use `get_terms( 'operator_offers' )`. This will by default hide any terms that are not associated with any post.

Comment: get_terms get all terms from all post types, i need all terms from ONE post type